# Glassfish Logging

Tags: logging, glassfish

Is there anyway to get glassfish to delete some of the old log files automatically?  Yesterday we had a disk full issue due to glassfish logging.  There is not apparent way to do this in the Admin Console, unless we are just ignorant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get Glassfish to delete the log files, in the Log Rotate Manager:
http://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/managing_rotated_log_files

Comment: In case any one else comes across this, the link has changed to https://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/managing_rotated_log_files

Comment: is this available in glassfish open source edition ?

Answer (score 4):

In 3.1 the command is now (supposed default of 10 does not exist)

```
asadmin> set-log-attributes com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=10
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#gkmai

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?  Neither of the other answers work anymore!

Comment: Works in 2017. This should be the accepted answer today!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot or do not want to install GlassFish Performance Advisor  as suggested in the other answer, another way is described in https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqDeleteRotatedLogs:

> The com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.max_history_files system property limits the number of rotated log files for both access logging and the server log

Comment: When I have tried this, I did not see any change (GlassFish 3.1.2.2)